# Get first line of stdin which is not in a file

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a function in a bash script that gets lines from stdin and picks out the first line which is not contained in a file.

Here is my approach:

```
doubles=file.txt

firstnotdouble(){ 
    while read input_line; do 
            found=0; 
            cat $doubles | 
            while read double_line; do 
                    if [ "$input_line" = "$double_line" ] 
                    then 
                            found=1; 
                            break 
                    fi 
            done 
            if [ $found -eq 0 ] # no double found, echo and break!
            then 
                    echo $input_line 
                    break 
            fi 
    done
}
```

After some debugging attempts I realized that when found is set to 1 in the first if block, it does not keep its value until the next if block. That's why it's not working. Why does the script act as if there were two found variables in different "scopes"?

The second question would be if the approach as a whole could be optimized.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: I would recommend reading through @EtanReisner's link, It is quite useful.

Comment: @chrisaycock bash uses single `=` signs to compare strings.  Double (`==`) is just a synonym for the single `=`: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: @chown Wow, I never realized that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the issue with environment variables is that the commands in a pipeline (that is, a series of commands separated by `|`) run in subshells, and each subshell has its own environment variables. You could have avoided the problem by avoiding the UUOC (useless use of cat), writing:

```
while read ...; do ... done < "$doubles"
```

instead of the pipeline.

---

A (much) faster way than using a `while read` loop repeatedly through the doubles file is to use grep:

```
# Specify the file to be scanned as the first argument
firstnotdouble() {
  while IFS= read -r double_line; do
    if ! grep -qxF "$double_line" "$1"; then
      echo "$double_line"
      return
    fi
  done
  return 1
}
```

In the `grep`:

- `-q` suppress print out, and stop on first match
- `-x` pattern must match the entire line
- `-F` pattern is a simple string instead of a regular expression.

In the `read`:

- `IFS=` avoids spaces being trimmed
- `-r` avoids backslashes being deleted

With GNU grep, you could use `-xF -m1` (or even `-xFm1` if you like being cryptic) instead of `-qxF`, and then leave out the `echo`. The grep extension `-m N` limits the number of matches found to `N`.